# Substitute number for a variable that is involved in differentiation

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

I have some expressions that involve the derivative of `y(x)` with respect to `x`. An example is below. I need to substitute `x = 0` in these expressions, to get rid of the zero terms.

```
P: x*%e^x*y+%e^x*y-
   %e^x*log(x+1)*('diff(y(x),x,2))-
   %e^x*log(x+1)*('diff(y(x),x,1))-
   (%e^x*('diff(y(x),x,1)))/(x+1);
```

But when I try

```
P, x = 0;
```

or

```
subst(x = 0, P);
```

I get the error

> diff: variable must not be a number; found: 0

So it doesn't want to put `x = 0` in `diff(y(x), x)`. Is there any way I can substitute `x = 0` for the occurrences of `x` *outside differentiation*? The expressions I have are very complicated, so I really need to get rid of these terms that are 0.

Comment: Try `at`. I can't look it up now, but see `? at` in the online documentation.

Comment: Yeah, looks like `at(P, x = 0)` has the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, this works like a charm! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I've done so -- hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`at` represents the value of an expression, but it's careful to avoid substituting a literal value into an expression for which it isn't valid, such as `diff`. From the problem statement:

```
(%i2) P: x*%e^x*y+%e^x*y-
   %e^x*log(x+1)*('diff(y(x),x,2))-
   %e^x*log(x+1)*('diff(y(x),x,1))-
   (%e^x*('diff(y(x),x,1)))/(x+1);
                                         2
          x       x       x             d
(%o2) x %e  y + %e  y - %e  log(x + 1) (--- (y(x)))
                                          2
                                        dx
                                                    x  d
                                                  %e  (-- (y(x)))
                       x             d                 dx
                   - %e  log(x + 1) (-- (y(x))) - ---------------
                                     dx                x + 1
(%i3) at(P, x = 0); 
                                    !
                           d        !
(%o3)                  y - -- (y(x))!
                           dx       !
                                    !x = 0
```

Just to clarify, aside from `diff`, `integrate`, and other expressions containing dummy variables, `at` effectively just substitutes the literal value.

```
(%i4) at(sin(x) + cos(x), x = a);
(%o4)                    sin(a) + cos(a)
```

I see a problem with the original problem statement -- it contains both `y` and `y(x)` -- which makes it hard to substitute some actual function for `y` later on. If it matters, you might want to use `y(x)` throughout, or to say `depends(y, x)` and then use `y` throughout.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I used `y` at some places after differentiating with respect to `x`, doing many calculations with the results, and finally realizing some terms with `y` were missing after differentiation :) I didn't know I had posted this version here.